# How to properly printf float (*)() in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I have these two lines of code that which I try to `printf` on the console, however, in objective-C I get an error saying that: `format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'float (*)()'`

How to properly make this works in Obj-C?

```
SomeValue = (float (*)())dlsym(someServices, "someMethod");
printf("%f\n", someValue);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`someValue` in your code is a function pointer, not a value returned from the corresponding function. If you need to print the value returned from that function, simply invoke it:

```
printf("%f\n", someValue());
//                      ^^
```

It goes without saying that you have to `NULL`-check anything that comes from `dlsym`.

Comment: Ah no wonder! Thanks for the helpful answer! May I ask an extra question if you don't mind? I try to compare the value of the returned by someValue in a statement but seems not to works, 'if (someValue() >= 0.000030) {some action}', any idea what is wrong here? Thanks again!

Comment: @GregorIsack That's odd: the code you show is supposed to compile. What error do you get?

Comment: Oh it compiled just fine, but the `some action` is not performed, which I'm guessing it has something to do with the operator. It was supposed to display an alert, however it doesn't. Using `printf` to double check the logic, the logic is right and the boolean should is true.

Comment: @GregorIsack Could this be a floating point precision problem? `0.000030` is of type `double`, so a conversion would be performed to deal with this comparison. What value gets printed when you debug?

Comment: in the case where it printed `0.000015` with the statement `if (someValue() <=0.000015) {displayAlert}`, it failed (the value of `someValue` keep changing as it's retrieved from device sensor), and I tried something like `if (someValue() <= (float)0.000015) {displayAlert}`, it failed too. That's really weird.

Comment: @GregorIsack When `0.000015` gets printed the value in `double` is actually `0.000014999999621068127453327178955078125`, so you should indeed get an alert. In general you should expect equality portion of your comparisons to fail for floats (i.e. assume that `<=` is the same as `<`). Equality works well only with a small subset of numbers - the ones composed of negative powers of 2, e.g. 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.75, 0.875, and so on. Use [this calculator](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_float.html) to see the actual value stored in float for a decimal value that you enter.